# SQLAlchemy: Table already exists

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

when do we generally get the following error in SQLAlchemy?

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1050, "Table 'foobar' already exists")
```

The `foobar` table does already exists, but why SQLAlchemy is trying to create table when already present. I'm assuming it shouldn't create table if already exists.

I'm using following syntax to create table:

```
t = Table('foobar', metadata,
      Column('col1', String(50), primary_key=True),
      Column('col2', String(100)),
      mysql_engine='InnoDB',
      mysql_charset='utf8')
```

(I'm calling the same program in parallel 10 times)

Comment: I assume you might have given a code snippet to show us what approach you are using, but eventually do you happen to have foreign keys in the t table or do you happen to have foreign key(s) referencing col1 or any other column on the t table? I am having a similar issue which I think is related to referential integrity.

Comment: I use the `checkfirst` argument, but I still get the `Table already exists` error.  Note, I'm using python's multiprocessing pool functionality.  It seems like this shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 22):

Just use schema object's **(Table,Index and Sequence)**  **create** and **drop** methods with **checkfirst=True**  **keyword** and table will automatically add an **"IF NOT EXISTS or IF EXISTS  CLAUSE"** whichever is appropriate to SQL.

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

```
t = Table('foobar', metadata,
  Column('col1', String(50), primary_key=True),
  Column('col2', String(100)),
  mysql_engine='InnoDB',
  mysql_charset='utf8')

t.create(checkfirst=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the foobar table already existed, you could instead have done:

```
users = Table('foobar', metadata, autoload=True)
```

and SQLAlchemy would have automatically figured out the table's structure from the database.

Check first using autoload, table is there or not, if it is not there then create the table.

Comment: what if the table doesn't exist? I don't think only passing `autoload` argument works if we would like to create table in first run.

Comment: Don't you check first, table is there or not already using autoload and it is not there then use your syntax for create table ?

Comment: The Table constructor with Column objects same as the existing table structure without `autoload` options works too. In SQLAlchemy it is not necessary to check if the table already exists or not. I came across the above `OperationalError` when I'm running the scripts through cron job. Just wondering what might've caused this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my guess with some troubleshooting ideas.  My guess is that the client **thinks** the table does not exist, because it can't see it, but when trying to create it, cannot because it in fact does exist.

Troubleshooting ideas:

- Check to see if maybe some other part of the code is writing to the same log file or whatever and is trying to create these tables.
- Manually login with the same ID and password as the client, and see if you can see the 
  table.
- Pass `echo=True` to `create_engine` to learn the exact queries the client performs, then repeat all the queries in your own SQL shell to see what the client is seeing.  Hopefully that will lead you to a conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use metadata:

```
database_engine = create_engine(
    'mssql+pyodbc://username:password=@server:1433/databaseName?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server?trusted_connection=no')
with database_engine.connect() as database_connection:
    metaData = MetaData(bind=database_engine, reflect=True)
    metaData.reflect()

    try:
        Table("tbl_stuff",
              metaData,
              Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
              Column("Name", String(255)),
              extend_existing=True)
        metaData.create_all(database_connection, checkfirst=True)
        metaData.reflect()
    except Exception as an_exc:
        logging.exception("Exception creating tbl_stuff: " + str(an_exc))
```

For details please see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html